# CSS DOM issue - cannot find a reason why property is being overwritten

Tags: css, dom

The site in question is 1000freewebsites.com. The specific pages I'm struggling with are:

- 1000freewebsites.com/signup.php
- 1000freewebsites.com/login.php

This site uses the skeleton framework and Ryan Fait's sticky footer. On these pages I have a div with the ID of #bluestripe that should fill the vertical space between the header and the footer.

There are three parent elements; #html, #body and .wrapper. All are set to height:100%; in the stylesheet. #bluestripe is also set to height:100% and min-height:100%. As I understand it, this should achieve the effect I desire. Do I have my theory wrong?

Using Chrome Inspector I find that the height attribute is crossed out for .wrapper. If my theory is correct, this explains why #bluestripe is not expanding to fill the vertical space.

I cannot find any element that over rides .wrapper's height setting. Can you see what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

this is your css:

```
.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important; //height here
margin: 0 auto -40px;
height: 100% ;//height again here
}
```

you are defining two times the height and as the first one got `!important` its overriding the second one

this cause another error, because the paddings and the other elements are pushing the `.container` div down, so if you change a few properties you can get rid of this behavior:

```
#bluestripe {
background: #0099cc;
width: 100%;
padding: 40px 0px 40px 0px;
border-top: 10px solid #666666;
/*height: 100%; drop this line*/
}

.wrapper {
background: #0099cc; /*add this line*/
min-height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -40px;
height: auto; /*acording to ryanfaits's css this is what mades the footer stick to the botom*/
}
```

this will made the `.bluestripe` shrink again but as the .wrapper still has the same background color, it doesn´t matters

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS rule for `.wrapper` has 2 height declarations. Get rid of the one setting height to auto.

```
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important; /* <- Get rid of this one */
    margin: 0 auto -40px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Doing that creates two new problems: 1) the div now extends well beneath the viewport, creating a scrolling effect 2)sticky footer breaks. You can see this at 1000freewebsites.com/signup.php Its late and so I'm going to head to bed and sleep on this. Any insight as to how to both preserve the sticky footer and have a full height content div is much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the edit :-) That, unfortunately, will not work because 1) I have content divs with different colored backgrounds on them on other pages and .wrapper is on every page. I've considered creating a .wrapper class specifically for these pages, but I use a templating system and that would start to get messy. 2) The elements in #bluestripe need to be vertically aligned on the page, so I need this container div to be full height. I am beginning to think a jquery sticky footer may be my only solution, which makes me sad.

Comment: Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/thefrontender/EHMHH/ I think this is the effect you're going for?